# Turn hex string into int (JAVA)

Tags: java, colors

So I am working on a project where there are 3 sliders(r, g, b) and I use `String.format("%02x%02x%02x", r, g, b);` to turn it into a hex string, my problem is that I cannot turn it into an int. I have searched the internet and could not find anything, the only one solution was `Integer.parseInt(hex, 16)` which gives me  a value of 87295 and my original color is 0054FF and I get 87295 *(the reason I need it as an int is because all of my void methods require a color in a hexadecimal in the form of an int)*

Comment: We could use more detail.  `Integer.parseInt(string,16)` *DOES* work, so the problem must be elsewhere.  When you say you get, the wrong answer, are you sure you're not looking at the number in decimal format?

Comment: 87295 decimal = 0154FF hex, so the only error here is you've apparently set the "r" term to 1 somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer assumed you are asking an [X - Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), which means it may not face to what you need in your question.

Assume `r`, `g`, `b` are of type `int`, also assume you don't need the Alpha color, then you can use a trick of bit manipulation like this, to directly use the original value to calculate the color value, without turning it into hex string.

```
int iColor = (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b;
```

Then this value can be used to turn into hex string for your further need.

```
String sColorHex = Integer.toHexString(iColor);
```

**Update**: Due to the comment of another answer, the alpha should not be ignored, and what the original question really need seems the color int value. Directly use this to get that required value:

```
int color = 0xFF000000 + (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b;
```

The original problem doesn't mention about the alpha color, so assume the alpha is 100% (0xFF), which shows as `0xFF000000` (= 0xFF << 24) above.

Answer (score 1):

```
Integer.parseInt(String s, 16);
```

is your friend in need.

> *Parses the string argument as a signed integer in the radix specified by the second argument... The resulting integer value is returned.*
>   [<sub>~ Java doc ~</sub>](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,%20int))

---

Example:

```
Integer.parseInt("0054FF", 16);
```

OUTPUT:

> 21759

The output does not match your specified output (87295). I believe your error is elsewhere in your code.

---

**EDIT:**

According to your comment,

```
Integer.decode(String s);
```

is what you need I guess.

Comment: So my method that requires a hexadecimal goes like the following "void drawBox(int x, int y, int color)" and the value required for color is like this "0xFFFFFFFF" but how would I use the number outputted by Integer.parseInt?

Comment: Well, the highest number for just RGB is 0xFFFFFF.  If you have an alpha channel, then you have all 32 bits.  But "how to use 0xFFFFFFFF" is that it's equal to -1 decimal, and that's what you use.  -1 has all the right bits set, doesn't matter if you use the decimal representation, it's still the same number (bit pattern) under the hood.  Try it and see, -1 should be all bits set, which is white. @Asyc